# Allegro Framework Cannot Be Found in Xcode

Tags: xcode, allegro, allegro5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Xcode 4 and Allegro 5.1 - Linker can't find Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487487/xcode-4-and-allegro-5-1-linker-cant-find-framework)

I've been trying to get Allegro working on my Mac running OS X 10.8.  I followed these instructions:

http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=OSX,_Xcode_4,_Framework

I go down and do everything they say for a simple Xcode application but it fails during the build with the following error:

> ld: framework not found Allegro-5.1
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've tried using Allegro 5.0.7 and 5.1.3 and both times I get the same result that it can't find the framework.  Am I missing something?  Here's my very basic app that I'm trying to run.

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    al_init();
    al_create_display(640, 480);
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb_f(1, 1, 0));
    al_flip_display();
    al_rest(5.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer for "[Xcode 4 and Allegro 5.1 - Linker can't find Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487487/xcode-4-and-allegro-5-1-linker-cant-find-framework)" helped me.

In the project target, go to "Build Settings" and change the "Framework Search Paths" to `/Library/Frameworks`.

Comment: It helped me as well. This has to be posted on Allegro's Wiki, since their setup topic doesn't say anything about this issue.
Thanks!