# Xcode 4 and Allegro 5.1 - Linker can't find Framework

Tags: xcode, xcode4, linker, allegro, allegro5

I know there are several other questions here regarding the Linker and Xcode 4, but they don't really relate to my problem.

I've built Allegro 5.1 and it took me a while because of FreeType, but eventually it worked. Now I've written a little Space Invader game using Allegro. But somehow the linker can't find the framework.

What I've done so far:

- The Frameworks are located at /Library/Frameworks/ and they have the same structure like all the other frameworks in that place
- I've added the frameworks to the "Link Binary With Libraries" tab of my target
- I've added them in a "Copy Files" tab on my target with Destination "Frameworks"
- I've added the correct path settings in the Build Settings, so the header files can be found

I've done all the right steps, but still I get:

```
ld: framework not found Allegro-5.1
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I already had a working framework, but it was installed as shared libs and not in "framwork mode". But adding the framework components to the project was kinda hard because they were stored in `/usr/local/lib`, which can't be selected with the file dialog...

So... I have no idea what else there should be to do. When I had the shared libs it worked, but now with the same setting but different location it doesn't anymore. Tell me if you need more information, I'll provide it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in case someone lands here, with the help of elias in the Allegro IRC I've found the "error":

In my targets `Build Settings` I had to specify the `Framework Search Paths` as `/Library/Frameworks`.

This doesn't really make sense to me, since this is the default directory for the Frameworks on Mac OS X, but whatever...